# Auto-update MYSQL table with JSON using python

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

I have a JSON

```
{
"data": {
    "message": { “success” }
    "user": {
        "id": "1234",
        "playlist": [
            [
                "title",
                "album",
                "artist",
                "info"
            ],
            [
                "title",
                "album",
                "artist",
                "info"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I want to fill MYSQL tables using the same. However i am a novice at python thus not sure how to do the same. How should i make sure that MYSQL tables are auto-updated when the JSON hits the server.

what i have tried is

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO json_col VALUES %s", title,album,artist,info)
```

Comment: are you trying to store json data as a whole in your table or update individual tables and fields in your database based on the json values?

Comment: You could use django + django rest famework and add a `ModelViewSet` to create an interface for this purpose. The benefit will be limited as you only store JSON in a column, without any intelligence. Other databases with JSON support may be more suitable.

Comment: Parse the values with python in order to insert the value for the corresponding column key, but you need to specify what value to what column, and your schema needs to match this.

Comment: @ Gil i am trying to update individual tables and fields in your database based on the json values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to insert your playlist values into corresponding fields in a table:

```
for list in dict['data']['user']['playlist']:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO json_col (title, album, artist, info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" % 
        (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]))
db.commit()
```

Comment: @ konart: thats precisely what i am trying to do. add playlist values from json to my tables.

Comment: @vedami So... was my answer helpful than?)